# Package that should exist in pacman database somehow does not

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman, atom-editor

A relatively new arch user speaking:

Atom package is listed [here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/atom/), But I don't have access to it through Pacman and `pacman -S atom` is responded with:

`error: target not found: atom`

Yes, my database is up-to-date, But I speculate that although the package is listed as x86_64, it has something to do with my OS being 32bit.

Comment: The architecture can indeed be an issue :-) Out of curiosity, how have you been able to run a configuration that is unsupported since late 2017?

Comment: @fra-san I love to maintain all of my older devices which are still functional. There has never been a serious issue so far BTW.

Comment: But, coming back to your question, that means that you haven't been able to install packages from the Arch repositories in a while (which may be an issue because you are not getting security patches), and there is no way you could except for those from the [Arch Linux 32 project](https://archlinux32.org/). I see there is no atom there, though. Can this be an answer to your question?

Comment: @fra-san I see. I didn't check that database. Thanks for your help. As far as I could see, packages including those relative to kernel still receive updates in the old 200MB-a-week Arch fashion. Anyway, It's not my main device. It only still exists and I don't think 64bit with 1GB is really a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Should have checked the database for 32-bit release which is  [Arch Linux 32 project](https://archlinux32.org/) but mistakenly checked the main release's database.

Comment: As I remember I installing atom easily, so my guest people with 64bit architecture should not visit the question.